# Accessing a CSV file hosted on Github with R

Tags: r, csv, github

I'd like to acces data from Github repositories directly from R.

When importing data, I get this error

> cols(`<!DOCTYPE html>` = col_character()) 60 parsing failures.

¿How can I fix that? My code:

```
data <- read_csv(curl("https://github.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/blob/master/AU_F_Properati_v2.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Augusto Welcome to SO, Kindly ask the question in english. As for the answer please try hitting this url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/master/AU_F_Properati_v2.csv"

Comment: Thanks, I use the url propused you, and to read all rows. ¿How I Can separate the colmuns?, I tried whith sep=";".

Answer (score 1):

The key, as @karthik commented, is to change the URL by replacing `https://github.com/`with `raw.githubusercontent.com/`, and skipping the `blob/` part.

i.e. changing:

> https://github.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/blob/master/AU_F_Properati_v2.csv

to:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/master/AU_F_Properati_v2.csv

(carefully compare the URLs and you'll spot the differences)

Besides that, it seems your .csv file is formatted using ";" as the field separator and "," as the decimal separator; this is common with data in languages such as Spanish, where the comma is reserved as the decimal separator.

To properly parse the file, simply use `read.csv2()` or `read_csv2()` i.e.:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata <- read_csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/master/AU_F_Properati_v2.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks, I cant`n does the same for another CSV: AU_URB <- read_csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datatto/AU25-de-Mayo/blob/master/AU_Unidad_1500_Data2.csv") , give me error: Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 404. ¿Should I configure something in github?

Comment: @AugustoTovarNumpaque I forgot to mention removing the `blob/` part of the address. 

I have updated my answer, it should be clear now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a short answer [here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/Download-from-Github/): One way is to use this line of code in R:

```
readr::read_csv("https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/file.name")
```